# Convert SVG into android animated vector drawables

Tags: android, android-animation, svg-animate

How can i convert this SVG file into a Animated vector drawable for android to show on the activity image.

SVG file

```
<svg width="38" height="38" viewBox="0 0 38 38" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#E31F64">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g transform="translate(1 1)" stroke-width="2">
            <circle stroke-opacity=".5" cx="18" cy="18" r="18"/>
            <path d="M36 18c0-9.94-8.06-18-18-18">
                <animateTransform
                    attributeName="transform"
                    type="rotate"
                    from="0 18 18"
                    to="360 18 18"
                    dur="1s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I used some online tools to convert it but they simply creates a vector not the animated vector
Here is the vector

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="38dp"
    android:height="38dp"
    android:viewportWidth="38"
    android:viewportHeight="38">

    <group
            android:translateX="1"
            android:translateY="1">
        <path
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:strokeAlpha=".5"
            android:strokeWidth="2"
            android:pathData="M 18 0 C 27.941125497 0 36 8.05887450305 36 18 C 36 27.941125497 27.941125497 36 18 36 C 8.05887450305 36 0 27.941125497 0 18 C 0 8.05887450305 8.05887450305 0 18 0 Z" />
        <path
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:strokeWidth="2"
            android:pathData="M36 18c0-9.94-8.06-18-18-18" />

    </group>
</vector>
```

How can i create animated out of this to show spinning oval.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [ShapeShifter](https://shapeshifter.design/) tool to create Animated Vector Drawable. It is a very basic tool yet fulfills the need.

Comment: I tried the ShapeShifter tool but it not able to read the fill colors and animation as well

Comment: After importing the SVG, create a group layer for path_2. Pivot the path_2 group to the center. Appy rotation animation from 0 to 360. Also, remove the fill color and mention color in stroke color.